# ¿Cómo leer archivo Excel desde código C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel

Estoy leyendo un archivo Excel de la siguiente forma y me funciona, pero siempre me sale este dialogo que me indica si deseo guardar cambios.

¿Qué puedo hacer para que no me aparezca?

Código C#:

```
public List<Person> LeerArchivo(string pathArchivo , IEngineTool Tool)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            List<Person> lp = new List<Person>();
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(pathArchivo);
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
            string strValue = string.Empty;

            for (int fila  = 2; fila <= rowCount; fila++)
            {
                for (int columna = 1; columna <= colCount; columna++)
                {
                    if (xlRange.Cells[fila, columna] != null && xlRange.Cells[fila, columna].Value != null)
                        strValue = strValue + xlRange.Cells[fila, columna].Value.ToString()  + "#" ;
                    else
                        strValue = strValue + "NO_DEFINIDO" + "#";
                }
                p=SetPerson(strValue);
                strValue = string.Empty;
            }

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);
            xlWorkbook.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
            xlApp.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

            return lp;
        }
```

Dialogo que nesecito eliminar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probablemente el problema se soluciona con un simple

```
Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

que evita que aparezcan avisos durante el tiempo en el que tienes la instancia de la aplicación abierta.